# How to make DIVs inline-block in rows?

Tags: css, positioning

What I'm trying to accomplish is something I'm new at - CSS positioning. I've learned a lot at Codecademy.com as far as HTML/CSS, but for a template with Joomla I'm a bit confused.

What I am trying to mimick are the rows of 3 divs across like seen on this page: http://www.theremixologists.com/props - I just don't know how to specify 3 content inline-blocks per row like how they have the names (Alicia & Mat, Richard & Jennifer, Kirsten & Jon) - 3 across | 5 down

Here is a mockup of what I'm trying to replicate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQpDd.jpg

3 divs across, and then new lines of divs below.

So far, I assume what I should be doing is the following:

HTML Sample Code pasted into specific Joomla page via the WYSIWYG editor (I'll be adding this code to a generic Joomla created page):

```
<div class="box_row1">  
<p>This is sample text for the first content box</p>  
</div>  
<div class="box">  
<p>This is sample text for the second content box</p>  
</div>  
<div class="box">  
<p>This is sample text for the third content box</p>  
</div>
```

And then the CSS would be pasted into the custom.css (for the template):

```
.box_row1 {  
 display: inline-block;  
 height: 100px;  
 width: 100px;  
 border-radius: 6px;  
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;  
 }
```

and then create classes for the second and third rows (but how do I make them rows)?

I'm just not sure how to begin a new line of 3 div's across. CSS positioning is a science in of-itself. Are those 3x15 bocks actually tables, or grid modules maybe? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Edit: Inspecting their page with Firebug shows me this snippit for each block:

.fullwidth .one_third{width:256px;}

I just don't understand how to make rows of divs. CSS positioning is confusing to me LOL. Le Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want here, I assume you want to make all the 3 div's `inline` and you are just making 1 as `inline`, this is no where a `positioning` issue, it's a `display` issue so give a common class to each of your div like

```css
.div_common {  
 display: inline-block;  
 height: 100px;  
 width: 100px;  
 border-radius: 6px;  
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;  
}
```

```
<div class="div_common">  
 <p>This is sample text for the first content box</p>  
</div>  
<div class="div_common">  
 <p>This is sample text for the second content box</p>  
</div>  
<div class="div_common">  
 <p>This is sample text for the third content box</p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what they are doing

```
<div class="big_box">
    <div class="box">  
        <p>This is sample text for the first content box</p>  
    </div>  
    <div class="box">  
        <p>This is sample text for the second content box</p>  
    </div>  
    <div class="box">  
        <p>This is sample text for the third content box</p>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Now the css

```css
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.big_box {
    width:600px;
}
.big_box .box {
    float:left;
    width:196px;
}
```